# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:


 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoPlayerController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the Error that I am facing. Please give me the solution

Comment: Do you have the Facebook SDK properly "installed" in your project? Looks like you are not linking against the Facebook SDK library. I'd double check the setup steps that Facebook provide in their documentation.

Comment: Yes I have. Plz give some other ansr

Comment: If you are getting that error then you are not linking the Facebook SDK properly. Show us the command line that Xcode is running for the link stage.

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved the problem.
Check the  Library Search Paths in Build Phases. Xcode might have confused your library and you may need to correct it yourself by filling it "../lib" which is your Facebook SDK folder.