# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So I am trying to implement this into my current project:

https://github.com/mobitar/MBAlertView

Wenn I try to use this in my app I get this error:

> Ld
>   /Users/florianschaal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Janssenapp-egfiwitwudiuhubsglmuhxxuafya/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Janssenapp.app/Janssenapp
>   normal armv7s
>       cd /Users/florianschaal/Developer/Janssenapp
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/florianschaal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Janssenapp-egfiwitwudiuhubsglmuhxxuafya/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/florianschaal/Developer/Janssenapp/Janssenapp/ZBarSDK -F/Users/florianschaal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Janssenapp-egfiwitwudiuhubsglmuhxxuafya/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/florianschaal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Janssenapp-egfiwitwudiuhubsglmuhxxuafya/Build/Intermediates/Janssenapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/Janssenapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Janssenapp.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/florianschaal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Janssenapp-egfiwitwudiuhubsglmuhxxuafya/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Janssenapp.app/Janssenapp
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MBSpinningCircle.o   "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut", referenced from:
>         -[MBAlertView animationWithValues:times:duration:] in MBAlertView.o   "_kCATransitionFade", referenced from:
>         -[UIView(Animations) addFadingAnimationWithDuration:] in UIView+Animations.o   "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut",
>   referenced from:
>         -[UIView(Animations) animationPop] in UIView+Animations.o
>         -[UIView(Animations) addPulsingAnimation] in UIView+Animations.o
>         -[UIView(Animations) addFadingAnimationWithDuration:] in UIView+Animations.o   "_kCATransitionFromBottom", referenced from:
>         -[UIView(Animations) addFadingAnimationWithDuration:] in UIView+Animations.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UIView+Animations.o   "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn", referenced from:
>         -[MBAlertView addDismissAnimation] in MBAlertView.o   "_kCAFillModeForwards", referenced from:
>         -[UIView(Animations) animationPop] in UIView+Animations.o
>         -[UIView(Animations) addPulsingAnimation] in UIView+Animations.o
>         -[MBAlertView animationWithValues:times:duration:] in MBAlertView.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced
>   from:
>         objc-class-ref in UIView+Animations.o
>         objc-class-ref in MBAlertView.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAKeyframeAnimation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UIView+Animations.o
>         objc-class-ref in MBAlertView.o   "_CATransform3DMakeScale", referenced from:
>         -[UIView(Animations) animationPop] in UIView+Animations.o
>         -[UIView(Animations) addPulsingAnimation] in UIView+Animations.o
>         -[MBAlertView addDismissAnimation] in MBAlertView.o
>         -[MBAlertView addBounceAnimationToLayer:] in MBAlertView.o
>         -[MBAlertView didSelectBodyLabel:] in MBAlertView.o
>         -[MBAlertView didHighlightButton:] in MBAlertView.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: If you don't need it, simply throw out the demo from that project, which seems to be the culprit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have downloaded MBAlertView repository than compiled the example project and it worked. After that i have added MBAlertView directory to my project and it started to work after i added QuartzCore.framework in Link Binary With Librarys section of Build Phases in project file.

Comment: Added the QuartzCore.framework and all error are gone now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just look at following questions that may help you

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559256/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are writing a high performance game and write in assembly, just turn off the armv7s architecture in the build settings. This doesn't make any difference for normal apps (it's the processor in the iphone5).

Comment: Build Settings : Valid Architectures - just remove the armv7s

Comment: Now i get this error:No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).

So how do i set armv7 active?

Comment: If valid architectures = armv7 then set Build active architectures to NO, it should only build the armv7. ALso make sure the architectures setting also only says armv7